# R getting column data type

Tags: r, class, alphanumeric

I am using combination of sapply and class command as below to understand data type in each column of a data.frame. But I want class command to ignore cells that dont have any alpanumeric character at all. For example, my salary column is mostly numeric and I want the class command to ignore "-" and then print the answer

how could I achieve the same?

```
salary1 <- c(21000, 1, 26800)
salary <- c(21000, "-", 26800)

em <- data.frame(salary1, salary)
sapply (em, class)
```

-----update1----------

I added 2 lines of code as below. I hoped that class of salary3 will be numeric, but R says that it is "character". Is there any way around?

```
salary3<-salary[salary!="-"]
class(salary3)
```

Comment: Even if you''ll remove the punctuations, you won't lose the class. At best scenario you will have `character` class instead of `factor` (for example) using `gsub`, how will R know it is a numeric column?

Comment: if R ignores "-" completely then it is a numeric column as only remaining values are 21000 and 26800. That's what I get for the column salary1

Comment: No it is not. The moment you've created `salary <- c(21000, "-", 26800)`, R won't know it is `numeric` column anymore. In order to tell R that this is a `numeric` column, you will have to do `as.numeric(salary)` or `as.numeric(as.character(salary))`, which will miss the whole point, isn't it?

Comment: I understand your comment. Is there any other way around?

Comment: i also tried to copy that column (without -) into another. But it didnt solve my problem...i have updated my question